# CKEditor5 getSelectedElement()

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am working with CKEditor 5 (Baloon Editor) and trying get selected text.
How can I do it?

I tried below code and got NULL:

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
    var selection = editor.model.document.selection;
    console.log(selection.getSelectedElement());             
} );
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, `selection.getSelectedElement()` returns `null` for text elements. It returns an element object when figure objects selected. You can use

```
selection.getFirstPosition().parent
```

or

```
Array.from(selection.getSelectedBlocks())
```

Comment: Another solution, depending what your goal is, `editor.model.document.selection.anchor.parent`